# Depth Map / Defoucs Map from Single Image - GPU

Tags: image-processing

Is anyone aware of simple algorithm to extract Depth Map / Defocus Map from a single regular image.

I found some algorithms, yet most of them require "Optimization" step which isn't suitable to GPU's.

It doesn't have to be 100% perfect, just good enough.

P.S.
Defocus Map - Greyscale Map of the "Blur" level of each pixel.

Comment: Whenever I see a question I can contribute I do that.

Regarding your other remarks, You're absolutely right, took care of that. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Calculating depth from a single image is inherently ill-conditioned. There will always be user input or assumptions about the scene required. These assumptions/inputs are used in optimization algorithms. I think this is your best option, because these will give the best results.

If you want to use optimization on (modern) GPU's, you can use something like [SpaXe](https://github.com/SpaXe/graph-cuts) or [CUDACuts](http://cvit.iiit.ac.in/papers/rtGCuts_2008.pdf). It's not impossible, but the usefulness depends on the application.

Comment: I'm looking for something very crude. Something which make a gray scale make according to "Sharpness" even would be great.